# How to await the on 'end' event of a Node Stream API?

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, stream

I need to wait for the task of this API to finish before moving to the next task.
How would I add a promise / await to this syntax?

I need to use the enqueue function and then wait for the stream to complete before continuing any further code. I have tried returning a promise withing the .on('end', {}) call but with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
const {SiteChecker} = require('broken-link-checker');

const siteChecker = new SiteChecker(options)
  .on('error', (error) => {})
  .on('robots', (robots, customData) => {})
  .on('html', (tree, robots, response, pageURL, customData) => {})
  .on('queue', () => {})
  .on('junk', (result, customData) => {})
  .on('link', (result, customData) => {})
  .on('page', (error, pageURL, customData) => {})
  .on('site', (error, siteURL, customData) => {})
  .on('end', () => {});

siteChecker.enqueue(siteURL, customData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost fine, but in order to use Promises you need to wrap the whole code in it. You'd achieve that like this:

```js
const {SiteChecker} = require('broken-link-checker');

const siteChecker = new SiteChecker(options)
  .on('error', (error) => {})
  .on('robots', (robots, customData) => {})
  .on('html', (tree, robots, response, pageURL, customData) => {})
  .on('queue', () => {})
  .on('junk', (result, customData) => {})
  .on('link', (result, customData) => {})
  .on('page', (error, pageURL, customData) => {})
  .on('site', (error, siteURL, customData) => {});

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => siteChecker
       .on('end', resolve) 
       // resolve is a function that you call when the work is done
       .on('error' => reject)
       // reject is the function you call when the task fails
       .enqueue(siteURL, customData);
);
```

Now I'm not sure how the `broken-link-checker` works in your case, but if you wanted to reuse the whole solution then it would be best to wrap the whole thing in the promise and return the `siteChecker` reference like this:

```js
const {SiteChecker} = require('broken-link-checker');

const siteChecker = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const _sitechecker = new SiteChecker(options)
    .on('error', (error) => {})
    .on('robots', (robots, customData) => {})
    .on('html', (tree, robots, response, pageURL, customData) => {})
    .on('queue', () => {})
    .on('junk', (result, customData) => {})
    .on('link', (result, customData) => {})
    .on('page', (error, pageURL, customData) => {})
    .on('site', (error, siteURL, customData) => {});
    .on('end', () => resolve(_sitechecker))
    // notice that the sitechecker is passed here
    .on('error' => reject);

    sitechecker.enqueue(siteURL, customData);
});
```

Both ways of writing this will wait until completion (or until the `end` event is emitted).